# Updating arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new to Java and am getting lost! I am making a programme that checks the arrays to see what seats are available and if they are it will update them so they are no longer available.

it is updating them but once I print out all of my arrays using a separate method it just prints the default set variable.

I know my code may be a bit messy I am still new and would appreciate any help on how to get it working right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Theatre {
    
    // creating the rows of seats

    public int[] rowOne = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    public int[] rowTwo = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    public int[] rowThree = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    static void buy_ticket(){

        //Allows you to use variables set in the class
        Theatre myObjTheatre = new Theatre();

        System.out.println("Please select a row (1-3):");
        Scanner row = new Scanner(System.in);
            int selectRow = row.nextInt();
        
        if(selectRow == 1){
            System.out.println("You have selected row 1.");
            System.out.println("Please select a seat (1-12):");
            Scanner seat = new Scanner(System.in);
            int selectSeat = seat.nextInt();
            if(selectSeat <= 12){
                if(myObjTheatre.rowOne[selectSeat-1] == 0){
                    System.out.println("You bought a ticket"); 
                    myObjTheatre.rowOne[selectSeat-1] = 1;
                    for(int i: myObjTheatre.rowOne){
                        System.out.print(i);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Seat is occupied");
                }
            }
            else if(selectSeat >= 13){
                    System.out.println("The chosen seat does not exist.");
                }
        }

        else if(selectRow == 2){
            System.out.println("You have selected row 2.");
            System.out.println("Please select a seat (1-16):");
            Scanner seat2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int selectSeat2 = seat2.nextInt();
            if(selectSeat2 <= 16){
                if(myObjTheatre.rowTwo[selectSeat2-1] == 0){
                    System.out.println("You bought a ticket"); 
                    myObjTheatre.rowTwo[selectSeat2-1] = 1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Seat is occupied");
                }
            }
            else if(selectSeat2 >= 17){
                    System.out.println("The chosen seat does not exist.");
                }
        }
        else if(selectRow == 3){
            System.out.println("You have selected row 3.");
            System.out.println("Please select a seat (1-20):");
            Scanner seat3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int selectSeat3 = seat3.nextInt();
            if(selectSeat3 <= 20){
                if(myObjTheatre.rowThree[selectSeat3-1] == 0){
                    System.out.println("You bought a ticket"); 
                    myObjTheatre.rowThree[selectSeat3-1] = 1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Seat is occupied");
                }
            }
            else if(selectSeat3 >= 21){
                    System.out.println("The chosen seat does not exist.");
                }
        }   
    }
    
    public static void print_seating_area() {
        Theatre myObjTheatre = new Theatre();
        // prints the rows
        for (int i = 0; i < myObjTheatre.rowOne.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myObjTheatre.rowOne[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < myObjTheatre.rowTwo.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myObjTheatre.rowTwo[i]);

        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < myObjTheatre.rowThree.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(myObjTheatre.rowThree[i]);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Welcome to the New Theatre");

        while(true){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Please select an option:");
        System.out.println("    1) Buy a ticket");
        System.out.println("    2) Print seating area");
        System.out.println("    3) Cancel a ticket");
        System.out.println("    4) List available seats");
        System.out.println("    5) Save to file");
        System.out.println("    6) Load from file");
        System.out.println("    7) Print ticket information and total price");
        System.out.println("    8) Sort tickets by price");
        System.out.println("    0) Quit");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter option:");

        //takes the user input to select an option
        Scanner menuOption = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = menuOption.nextInt();

        if(option == 1){
            buy_ticket();
        }
        else if(option == 2){
            print_seating_area();
        }
    }
}   


}
```

Comment: Side recommendation: It would be best to separate all UI (user interface) code from the "business logic" code, meaning that your Theater class should have the private array fields plus methods that set, get and change the information, but should have no println statements (except perhaps temporary println statements for debugging), and should not use a Scanner. The UI code (println's and the Scanner) should be elsewhere, perhaps in the main method or perhaps in a driver class. This will help simplify your code and make it easier to debug and to enhance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints out the seating from a *new theater object that you just created.*  Of course the seats are all empty.

```
public static void print_seating_area() {
    Theatre myObjTheatre = new Theatre();
```

To fix this, you should really make `buyTicket()` and `printSeating()` non-static, so they operate on the Theater object directly.  Then call those methods from `main` on an object you create once.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Theatre myObjTheatre = new Theatre();
   System.out.println("Welcome to the New Theatre");

    while(true){
        // etc.
    
    if(option == 1){
        myObjTheatre.buy_ticket();
    }
    else if(option == 2){
        myObjTheatre.print_seating_area();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried that and the same problem still occurs not sure what's going on

Comment: @HarryWebb: if you've tried it and "it's not working", then show this in your question. It's very hard to debug "it's not working" without code and detailed descriptions.